# Calculate sin(x) and cos(x) using Taylor Series in C

Tags: c, performance, trigonometry, taylor-series

(It's different from the other question. Mine uses Taylor Series recursively as the other uses the MacLaurin Expansions of the functions)

I made a C program to calculate the sine and cosine of a number using Taylor Series. It works fine, but it takes a lot of time for bigger numbers. I want to know how can I improve my code to work faster. I thought about the intervals of both functions where f(x)=0, but I don't know if it helps and how can I use them in the code.

I did it recursively and the (x-a) term always equals 1. So a=x-1.

Can somebody help me please? I'd be grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long int fat(int a);
double sen(int n);
double coss(int n);

int main(void){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%f %f\n",sen(n),coss(n));
    return 0;
}

unsigned long int fat(int a){
    unsigned long int x;
    if (a==0) return 1;
    else{
         for(x=1;a>0;a--) x=x*a;
         return x;
    }
}

double sen(int n){
    int x,i;
    double r;
    if(n==0) return 0;
    for(x=r=0,i=1;x<10;x++,i++){
         if(i==5) i=1;   
         if(i==1) r+=(sen(n-1))/(fat(x));
         if(i==2) r+=(coss(n-1))/(fat(x));
         if(i==3) r-=(sen(n-1))/(fat(x));
         if(i==4) r-=(coss(n-1))/(fat(x));
    }
    return r;
}

double coss(int n){
    int x,i;
    double r;
    if(n==0) return 1;
    for(x=r=0,i=1;x<10;x++,i++){
        if(i==5) i=1;   
        if(i==1) r+=(coss(n-1))/(fat(x));
        if(i==2) r-=(sen(n-1))/(fat(x));
        if(i==3) r-=(coss(n-1))/(fat(x));
        if(i==4) r+=(sen(n-1))/(fat(x));
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I expect you want [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), particularly since you call sen coss and fat multiple times for the same input. Or e.g. for fat you can just precompute it for 0-9 and store that in an array.

Comment: Taylor series only work well for small values of x. Perhaps you should normalize input x to be in canonical range `(-pi,+pi)`, because `sin(x)=sin(x+2*pi*n)` for any n.

Comment: @RafaelSantos: to make input value smaller, simply replace it using something like this: `x=x - int(x/(2*pi))*2*pi`.

Comment: Memoization helped a bit, but the real problem is the number of times the code runs because of the recursions :/

Comment: @mvp what do you mean? I didn't get it

Comment: Really? With memoization you should run coss and sen exactly once for each value between 1 and n (and only one of the two at n), so you should avoid the exponential blow-up you're seeing.

Comment: @RafaelSantos: it's basic property of all trigonometric functions, as they have period 2*pi. You can make input number (I guess you're using n, but I prefer to call it x) smaller by removing or adding 2*pi increments, without changing your answer.